# Multiple selects really needed?

Tags: sql

I have the following table.

```
____________________________________
| carid | changeid | data1 | data2 | 
|_______|__________|_______|_______|
| 1     | 1        |a      |b      |
| 1     | 2        |c      |d      |
| 1     | 3        |e      |f      |
| 2     | 3        |g      |h      |
| 2     | 2        |i      |j      |
| 2     | 4        |k      |l      |
| 3     | 5        |m      |n      |
| 3     | 1        |o      |p      |
| 4     | 6        |q      |r      |
| 4     | 2        |s      |t      |
|_______|__________|_______|_______|
```

I want to select the following result:

---

```
| carid | changeid | data1 | data2 | 
|_______|__________|_______|_______|
| 1     | 1        |a      |b      |
| 1     | 2        |c      |d      |
| 1     | 3        |e      |f      |
| 3     | 5        |m      |n      |
| 3     | 1        |o      |p      |
|_______|__________|_______|_______|
```

In words: 
If a row has changeid=1 I want to select all the rows with the same carid as the row with changeid=1.

This problem is quite easy to solve with a query using multiple selects. First select all rows with changeid=1 and take those carids and select all rows with those carids. Simple enough.

I was more wondering if it is possible to solve this problem **without** using multiple selects? Preferably I'm looking for a faster solution but I can try that out myself.

Comment: Can you show us your query and the execution plan?  What database server are you using?  Why the restriction on multiple selects?

Comment: I was thinking something like the query tezzo showed below. The database or the restriction on multiple selects is of less importance since I guess this is more of an academic interest I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join the table back to itself

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM YourTable a
INNER JOIN YourTable b ON b.carid = a.carid and b.changeid = 1
```

Table a is all the rows you want to output, filtered by table b which limits the set to those with changeid = 1.

This should have excellent performance as everything is done in a set oriented manner.

`DISTINCT` may not be necessary if changeid 1 may only occur once, and should be avoided if possible as it may introduce a significant performance hit for a large result set.

Answer (score 1):

For multiple select you mean using IN?

```
SELECT carid, changeid, data1, data2
FROM YourTable
WHERE carid IN (SELECT carid FROM YourTable WHERE changeid = 1)
```

Comment: That is pretty much what I do yes. I was just wondering if it is possible to get around the use of the second select.

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support window functions.  You can do this as:

```
select carid, changeid
from (select t.*,
             max(case when changeid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over 
                 (partition by carid) as HasChangeId1
      from YourTable t
     ) t
where HasChangeId1 = 1;
```

If the "1" is the minimum value for the change id, this can be simplified to:

```
select carid, changeid
from (select t.*,
             min(changeid) over (partition by carid) as MinChangeId
      from YourTable t
     ) t
where MinChangeId = 1;
```

Comment: This solution also has two selects and I don't quite see the advantage over the one tezzo proposed (it also has two selects). The only difference is that you place yours in the "from section" when he is using IN in the "where section"

Comment: @Vejto . . . In databases that support window/analytic functions, such functions usually perform better than joins and `in` queries.

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like you're after only the combinations of carid and changeid present in the table, in which case the DISTINCT will return only the unique combinations for you. Not sure if that is what you're after but give it a go and check it for your expected behaviour...

```
SELECT DISTINCT CARID, CHANGEID FROM UnknownTable
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for since each row will probably carry more information.

Comment: In that case you will want a GROUP BY. If you put some extra columns on to you example dataset and indicate how you want these handled, I will adjust the SQL accordingly.

Comment: I highly doubt that GROUP BY will do the trick but I might have missed some. Added some extra tables, basically I want all the data to remain the same. Just get rid of the rows that are not interesting.

Comment: So something like `SELECT * FROM UnkownTable where CARID IN(1,3) AND CHANGEID IN(1,2,3,4)`?

Comment: You might have misunderstood it a little. I do not know exactly which carid's I'm interested in. All I know is I want those carids which have at least one row in which changeid = 1. Perhaps that sentence hellp your understand, I'm afraid it is not too easy to describe

Comment: Ah... in that case @Tevo's answer is probably the way to go